# Problem with intellij idea rename variable?

Tags: variables, intellij-idea, rename

When I try to rename a variable using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> or simply Refactor => Rename, sometimes intellij renames not only the one I want to, but also some other variables (in other files) with the same name and all their references which are completely irrelevant.

When I further studied that behavior I got to know that it happens ***only*** for ***public*** variables. Refer below screenshot. I tried to rename the squared variable (keywords). There are lots of totally irrelevant code lines are suggested below to rename accordingly.

[image]

Do some one know what the exact problem here? And a convenient solution?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the option to **search in comments and strings** in the Rename dialog:

[image: search]

The option is available when you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> twice.

Comment: Its not about comments or strings. just fields/variables.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will help us to reproduce and fix the issue.

Comment: will get back to you asap.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne IDE finds occurrences in comments and strings, you need to disable the option shown on the screenshot.